# Is there a flag I can pass to either `df` or `mount` to make them display results for only locally-mounted file systems?

Tags: linux, nfs, mount, server-message-block, grep

I'm getting mighty tired of having to manually [egrep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/egrep) out [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System_%28protocol%29)- and [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_%28software%29)-mounted file systems whenever I am checking on the condition of locally-mounted file systems.

Is there some combination of flags that I can pass to either `df` or `mount` that will force them to display *only* local file systems and skip any and all network-mounted ones?

Comment: Similar [question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029493/how-can-i-stop-snaps-from-listing-in-df).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `-t` and `-x` flags for `df` will do what I'm looking for.

`-t [type]` will list file systems matching filesystem type [type]

`-x [type]` will list file systems *not* matching file system type [type]

I.e., for me to exclude NFS-mounted filesystems, the command is `df -x nfs`.

Comment: What are some more possible values of '[type]'? For example, for the loop devices, e.g. `/dev/loop27`?

Comment: E.g., `df -h -x squashfs -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs` will cut down the output to that of earlier times.

Comment: Or in other words, I suggest ***extending the answer*** to be a little bit more generally applicable, for example, including how that '[type]' information can be located. (But ****** ****** ***without*** ****** ****** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building: *"Last seen more than 6 years ago"*. Perhaps somebody is willing to do it?

Answer (score 16):

`df -l`.  This depends on network filesystems being properly identified as such, though.

Comment: Super, very straightforward solution.

Comment: `df -l` still shows many loop-devices like `/snap/gnome-calculator` or `/snap/core/`

Comment: What does "property identified" mean? Must it have the `_netdev` mount option, or is it some other detection logic in the background?